# How to Get Number of Months and Days From Two Dates

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have two tables:

```
AgeMilestones //Represents available timespans
Id int     
Description varchar //(newborn, 1 month old, 2 month old, etc.)
NbrMonths int //( 0, 1, 2, etc.)
NbrDays int //(0, 1, 2, etc.)   


Child
Id int     
DateOfBirth DateTime
```

I need to get the AgeMilestones that a given child has **currently** passed in age. The problem is that a real month can have 28 days, 30 days or 31 days. So if I convert **NbrMonths** into days, I may occasionally be off by a few days.

Is there any other way to do this that would be more accurate using the existing the table structure?

**EDIT:** 
I need to figure what agemilesstone corresponds to the number of months/days that exist in the time between the child was born and today(something similar to below). I am getting tripped up in cases where an age milestone may be 3 months and 15 days, or 5 months and 7 days...

```
SET @Days = DateDiff(d,child.DateOfBirth, GetDate())  
SET @Months = DateDiff(m,child.DateOfBirth, GetDate()) 

SELECT * FROM AgeMileStone WHERE NbrMonths < @Months AND NbrDays < @Days
```

Problem with records like
***AgeMilestone:*** 
Id: 4
Description: "5 and 1/2 months"
Months: 5
Days: 15

Comment: Don't forget that a month can have 29 days too. Not very often, but it happens. I heard babies can be born on that day too, but I've got not actual proof of that.

Comment: You already know it, I don't get your updated question.

Comment: I guess I know what you're talking about... You mean to say that NbrDays are actually offset-days, not total days since the DOB, correct?

Comment: @Denis Valeev - I suppose so, yes. A child maybe 0 months old with a 2-4 day offset (for a "2-4 Day Old" agemilestone)

Comment: Why do you need to be so specifically granular with the milestones? The milestones are supposed to be approximate. A baby doesn't know how many days are in a particular month and his/her  rate of development doesn't actually change depending on the number of days in a particular month. If a baby is 32 days old, he is "1 month" old and not "1 month and 2 days" or "1 month and 1 day" or "1 month and 4 days". That would make the logic pretty hard because in case of a 32 day old baby "1 month and 2 days" could equal "1 month and 1 day".  Can you give real examples of the milestones you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this solves it because the `DATEADD` function will take care of add the months and days appropriately given the starting date of birth:

```
declare @AgeMilestones table (
    NbrMonths int not null,
    NbrDays int not null,
    [Description] varchar(64) not null
)

declare @Child table (
    ChildId int not null identity,
    Name varchar(32) not null,
    DateOfBirth datetime not null
)

insert @AgeMilestones values (5, 15, '5 and 1/2 months')
insert @AgeMilestones values (0, 0, 'newborn')

insert @Child values ( 'Yearling', '2010-01-01' )
insert @Child values ( 'Newborn', GETDATE() )

declare @currentChild int = 2

select
    m.*
from @Child c
inner join @AgeMilestones m
    on dateadd(month, m.NbrMonths, dateadd(day, m.NbrDays, c.DateOfBirth)) <= getdate()
where c.ChildId = @currentChild
```

Comment: I think you should add days after you've added months and not the other way around.

Comment: I'm not sure that would matter

Comment: ... because of DOB in the middle of the month, I suppose you could truncate the DOB to the first of the month, then add the months then add the DOB days and the NbrDays

Comment: Solves my problem and plugs into my query perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's quite easy to do using `datediff(month, DOB, getdate())`.

Something like this:

```
declare @dob datetime = getdate() - 123; --born 123 days ago

select cast(datediff(month, @dob, getdate()) as varchar) + ' month old'
,cast(datediff(day, @dob, getdate()) as varchar) + ' days old'
```

**Update**

```
declare @dob datetime;
set @dob = getdate() - 125;

select 
datediff(month, @dob, getdate()) [Months], 
datediff(day, dateadd(month, datediff(month, @dob, getdate()), @dob), getdate()) [Offset Days]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I can get the number of days and number of months from the dateofbirth using datediff but I need to find the corresponding age mile stone. I edited my orginal post to try to give a better idea of what I am trying to do.

Comment: +1 Thanks again, this would have allowed me to eventually get where I wanted, but @Dave's solution is actually exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest utilizing something like this:

```
DATEPART(Month, NOW())
DATEPART(DAY, NOW())
```

try using

SELECT datepart(dayofyear, c.DateOfBirth) as 'doy' from child c

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that uses the AgeMilestones table you have and the [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) function, which returns the list of milestones for a child born on a particular day.

```
-- setup the AgeMilestone table with some initial data
CREATE table AgeMilestone (milestone_month int, milestone_name varchar(50))
insert into AgeMilestone (milestone_month, milestone_name) values (1, '1 month')
insert into AgeMilestone (milestone_month, milestone_name) values (2, '2 month')
insert into AgeMilestone (milestone_month, milestone_name) values (3, '3 month')
insert into AgeMilestone (milestone_month, milestone_name) values (4, '4 month')
...
insert into AgeMilestone (milestone_month, milestone_name) values (12, '12 month')
insert into AgeMilestone (milestone_month, milestone_name) values (24, '24 month')

Declare @DOB DATETIME = '1/14/2009'
SELECT 
     milestone_month, milestone_name
FROM AgeMilestone
where DATEADD(month, milestone_month, @DOB) <= GETDATE()
```